# SSRS 2012 - Is it possible to capture the SQL sent to the datasource?

Tags: oracle, ssrs-2012

Within an SSRS dataset, the sql script may be constructed using the parameters provided to the dataset.  Therefore the resulting script may be filled with errors caused by adding parameters.

In SSRS, is it possible to capture the resulting SQL Script that is sent to the DataSource?  The intent is to understand the vague errors that appear during SSRS development by reviewing the finalized sql text that is sent.

Comment: Can you not just profile the database?

Comment: More specifically, use SQL Profiler.

Comment: The data source is Oracle and I do not have access to it to get the sql applied to it.  I am hoping there is a way to capture the sql before it is sent to the Data Source.  The dev tool is Visual Studio 2010 with the 2012 data tools.

Comment: As a temporary solution in your dev environment, you can write the sql to a text box on the report.

Comment: How would the finalized sql text be available?  What property is used?

Answer (score 0):

Not has elegant as profile the database but if you are constructing the SQL as an expression you can add another parameter of type text and add the expression as the default value of that parameter.